# The entity with a name = 'RecordCountSnapshot' was not found in the MetadataCache

Tags: deployment, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We recently deployed updates to our CRM (UR13) as an unmanaged solution from our dev environment. For some unknown reason this removed customisations from 3 OptionSet fields on the account entity causing data corruption hell when noticed 5 days later =/.

Anyway I'm willing to put down to an anomaly for the timebeing, I only bring it up for the background. To resolve the issue, re-importing the unmanaged solution (which includes the account entity) should rebuild these OptionSets. I created 2 test environments, one from a Live backup before the unmanaged solution was deployed and another representing it's current state.

Importing the same solution package into *either test environment* now results in `The entity with a name = 'RecordCountSnapshot' was not found in the MetadataCache.` error being thrown. which raises questions like how did I manage to import the solution into the Live environment in the first place? That's not all, it appears that most **any** solution deployed to these environments will throw the same error making repair/future customisation seemingly impossible!

The `RecordCountSnapshot` hidden entity is present as a table in all SQL databases and is present in Metadata queries I perform. [This forum post](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/104521.aspx#) is the only useful reference to the issue I have found on the issue, but it's sadly unresolved.

If anyone can provide even the smallest insight that might help resolve this issue I'd be very appreciative XD.

---

**EDIT:**

W3WP Trace file as @Daryl requested - if you need any more info, please let me know.

FYI I have run the query mentioned in this trace manually and it returns 346 results without a problem

```
>Query execution time: 0.0 seconds; database: Organisation_MSCRM_220713_2330; Server:PY3-CRMTEST; command: select 
"recordcountsnapshot0".ObjectTypeCode as "objecttypecode"
, "recordcountsnapshot0".Count as "count"
, "recordcountsnapshot0".RecordCountSnapshotId as "recordcountsnapshotid" 
from
 RecordCountSnapshot as "recordcountsnapshot0" (NOLOCK) .
[2013-07-31 16:24:53.614] Process: w3wp |Organization:2c22b814-38f9-e211-8151-00155d143602 |Thread:   14 |Category: Exception |User: 9b39cd7c-231c-4c66-9459-327009bcb0ef |Level: Error |ReqId: a0ac1144-4cce-43b1-bc27-08484d9a73bc | CrmException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x0
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Int32 errorCode)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at DynamicMetadataCache.GetEntity(String entityName, NameMappingType mapping)  ilOffset = 0x13
    at BusinessEntityCollection.get_EntityMetadata()  ilOffset = 0x37
    at BusinessProcessObject.FillEntityCollectionFromDataReader(BusinessEntityCollection entities, IDataReader reader, EntityExpression entityExp, Boolean useEntityExpression, String aggregateLimitExceededName, Boolean quickFindRecordLimitCheckRequired, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x70
    at BusinessProcessObject.QueryAndFillEntityCollection(CrmDbConnection dbConnection, IDbCommand dbCommand, BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, PagingHelper pagingHelper, Boolean useEntityExpression, String aggregateLimitExceededName, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x4D
    at BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple(BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, PagingHelper pagingHelper, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x41
    at BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple(BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x40
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x76
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at RecordCountCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x25
    at CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x26
    at RecordCountCache.RetrieveRecordCount(Int32 objectTypeCode, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at SecurityExtensionRetrieveMultipleHelper.GetRetrieveMultipleSecurityFilterOption(RetrieveMultipleSecurityFilterPopulatorInitializationData initializationData, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x7A
    at SecurityExtension.CreateSecurityFilter(Guid user, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FilterExpression existingCriteria, ExecutionContext context, Boolean noLock, LinkEntityType linkEntityType, RetrieveMultipleSecuritySqlFormat& securitySqlFormat)  ilOffset = 0x3E
    at SecurityExtension.AddSecuritySql(Guid user, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x28
    at SecurityExtension.PreRetrieveMultipleHandler(ExtensionEventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at PreRetrieveMultipleEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ExtensionEventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x5F
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at ImportSolutionConfigurationPageHandler.ImportItem()  ilOffset = 0x60
    at ImportHandler.Import()  ilOffset = 0x43
    at RootImportHandler.ImportAndUpdateProgress(ImportHandler ih)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at RootImportHandler.HandleNonMetadataHandlers(String[] ImportEntities, ImportHandler& ihForCurrentPath)  ilOffset = 0x33
    at RootImportHandler.RunImport(String[] ImportEntities)  ilOffset = 0x1D8
    at ImportXml.RunImport(String[] ImportEntities)  ilOffset = 0xE
    at ImportXml.RunImport()  ilOffset = 0x5B3
    at ImportXmlService.ImportSolutionSkipCapable(Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Byte[] customizationFile, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, Boolean skipProductUpdateDependencies, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x46
    at RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)  ilOffset = 0x101
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)  ilOffset = 0x4F
    at InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  ilOffset = 0x57
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x50
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1C5
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)  ilOffset = 0x156
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)  ilOffset = 0x145
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x24
    at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()  ilOffset = 0xF6
    at ImportSolutionCommand.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x20
    at DataSource.ImportSolution(Byte[] customizationFile, Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, Boolean skipProductUpdateDependencies, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ImportSolution()  ilOffset = 0x11E
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ProcessRequestData()  ilOffset = 0x4A
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ProcessAction(String action)  ilOffset = 0x92
    at AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0xD
    at Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()  ilOffset = 0x54
    at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x69E
    at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at Page.ProcessRequest()  ilOffset = 0x14
    at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0x31
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x11D
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x15
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x10E
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0xFC
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x45
>Crm Exception: Message: The entity with a name = 'RecordCountSnapshot' was not found in the MetadataCache., ErrorCode: -2147217150
[2013-07-31 16:24:53.614] Process: w3wp |Organization:2c22b814-38f9-e211-8151-00155d143602 |Thread:   14 |Category: Platform.Sql |User: 9b39cd7c-231c-4c66-9459-327009bcb0ef |Level: Error |ReqId: a0ac1144-4cce-43b1-bc27-08484d9a73bc | BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple  ilOffset = 0x41
    at BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple(BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, PagingHelper pagingHelper, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x41
    at BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple(BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x40
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x76
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at RecordCountCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x25
    at CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x26
    at RecordCountCache.RetrieveRecordCount(Int32 objectTypeCode, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at SecurityExtensionRetrieveMultipleHelper.GetRetrieveMultipleSecurityFilterOption(RetrieveMultipleSecurityFilterPopulatorInitializationData initializationData, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x7A
    at SecurityExtension.CreateSecurityFilter(Guid user, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, FilterExpression existingCriteria, ExecutionContext context, Boolean noLock, LinkEntityType linkEntityType, RetrieveMultipleSecuritySqlFormat& securitySqlFormat)  ilOffset = 0x3E
    at SecurityExtension.AddSecuritySql(Guid user, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x28
    at SecurityExtension.PreRetrieveMultipleHandler(ExtensionEventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0x19
    at PreRetrieveMultipleEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ExtensionEventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x5F
    at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveMultiple(EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at ImportSolutionConfigurationPageHandler.ImportItem()  ilOffset = 0x60
    at ImportHandler.Import()  ilOffset = 0x43
    at RootImportHandler.ImportAndUpdateProgress(ImportHandler ih)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at RootImportHandler.HandleNonMetadataHandlers(String[] ImportEntities, ImportHandler& ihForCurrentPath)  ilOffset = 0x33
    at RootImportHandler.RunImport(String[] ImportEntities)  ilOffset = 0x1D8
    at ImportXml.RunImport(String[] ImportEntities)  ilOffset = 0xE
    at ImportXml.RunImport()  ilOffset = 0x5B3
    at ImportXmlService.ImportSolutionSkipCapable(Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Byte[] customizationFile, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, Boolean skipProductUpdateDependencies, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x46
    at RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)  ilOffset = 0x101
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)  ilOffset = 0x4F
    at InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  ilOffset = 0x57
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x50
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1C5
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)  ilOffset = 0x156
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)  ilOffset = 0x145
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x24
    at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()  ilOffset = 0xF6
    at ImportSolutionCommand.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x20
    at DataSource.ImportSolution(Byte[] customizationFile, Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Boolean publishWorkflows, Guid importJobId, Boolean convertToManaged, Boolean skipProductUpdateDependencies, IOrganizationContext context)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ImportSolution()  ilOffset = 0x11E
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ProcessRequestData()  ilOffset = 0x4A
    at SolutionImportProcessPage.ProcessAction(String action)  ilOffset = 0x92
    at AppUIPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0xD
    at Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()  ilOffset = 0x54
    at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x69E
    at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at Page.ProcessRequest()  ilOffset = 0x14
    at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0x31
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x11D
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x15
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x10E
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0xFC
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x45
>Exception when executing query: select 
"recordcountsnapshot0".ObjectTypeCode as "objecttypecode"
, "recordcountsnapshot0".Count as "count"
, "recordcountsnapshot0".RecordCountSnapshotId as "recordcountsnapshotid" 
from
 RecordCountSnapshot as "recordcountsnapshot0" (NOLOCK)  Exception: Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.EntityMetadataNotFoundException: The entity with a name = 'RecordCountSnapshot' was not found in the MetadataCache.
   at Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.DynamicMetadataCache.GetEntity(String entityName, NameMappingType mapping)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessEntityCollection.get_EntityMetadata()
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.FillEntityCollectionFromDataReader(BusinessEntityCollection entities, IDataReader reader, EntityExpression entityExp, Boolean useEntityExpression, String aggregateLimitExceededName, Boolean quickFindRecordLimitCheckRequired, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.QueryAndFillEntityCollection(CrmDbConnection dbConnection, IDbCommand dbCommand, BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, PagingHelper pagingHelper, Boolean useEntityExpression, String aggregateLimitExceededName, ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrieveMultiple(BusinessEntityCollection entities, EntityExpression entityExp, DatabaseQueryTarget queryTarget, PagingHelper pagingHelper, ExecutionContext context)
```

Comment: Do you get any additional error information if you turn on server tracing?

Comment: I can't see anything extra except the SQL Query that failed.. then a stacktrace before it lists the error in exactly the same way, it didn't strike me as perticularly useful.. But I'll put it in an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repaired by upgrading to RU14, I've listed all the potentially relevant fixes from the [upgrade documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849744) but none of them seem to match the issue I was seeing but it could've been a compound effect. Personally I think it's more likely that the issue was caused by some file corruption that was repaired implicitly by the upgrade.

- When you import text data, a "SecLib::CheckPrivilege" error occurs.
- After you import a managed solution in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, labels on the form for the solution display incorrect information.
- Assume that a data import operation fails for some records in a nondefault organization. When you try to export the failure history, you receive an error message that states that the record is unavailable.